# Multiple tags for 'Favorite tags'

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, tag-watching

I can understand that `Favorite tags` option helps us to highlight the questions on the list with selected tags. I'd like to know if we can add multiple tags to that. For eg., adding `java+multithreading` should highlight only those question which is both tagged as `java` and `multithreading`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently this feature is implemented using an **OR** condition. It will display questions with Java or multithreading or both. Personally I feel it should still continue to function in this way only instead of changing it to use AND.

Comment: The current feature is good. I was just wondering if there is any option to get the `AND` feature.

Comment: @bdhar - Its not available currently in SE sites.