# Server error when attempting to see more linked questions here on MSE

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, linked-questions, 500-server-error

I tried to check the linked questions of [Build and strengthen the Stack Exchange community with "crossover questions" between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199989) by clicking on "more linked questions" on the right, which goes to https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/199989.

However, I got a server error when doing so: https://meta.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/questions/linked/199989

Can this please be fixed?

Comment: yup, I can confirm the error happening. Also happens in other MSE questions, but not on question on other sites (I tested on TWP and it was ok)

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing/314020#314020

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened only for folks in [the Custom Question Lists alpha](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313940/custom-question-lists-is-available-for-testing) - the linked view piggybacks on the normal question list view, but lacks the necessary information to drive the new custom list.

As of this morning, the old/normal question view will be forced for linked questions even for folks testing the alpha.