# Unanswered questions by tag without my answer

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer, unanswered-questions

How can I get **unanswered (unaccepted) questions** by **tag** that are **not answered by me** on Stack Overflow?

I want to answer users who did not get a satisfying answer. But every time I open the unanswered tab, it will list those questions also, which I answered.

Can someone please suggest a Data Explorer query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1370325?tags=java%2Candroid&UserId=6891563) that does that selection for you.

You'll need to enter your userid (found in the URL of your user profile) and one or more tags, separated by a comma.

It will sort the results by descending creationdate and then show the top 100 results.

```
select top 100
       q.id as [Post Link]
     , q.score
     , q.creationdate
     , q.tags
     , q.answercount
from posts q 
inner join posttags pt 
      on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t 
      on t.id = pt.tagid
inner join string_split(##tags:string?android,java##,',') sel 
      on sel.value = t.tagname
where q.id not in (
   -- all answers from the OP
   select parentid  -- question id
   from
   posts a
   where a.posttypeid = 2 -- A
   and a.owneruserid = ##userid?6891563##
)
-- and q.answercount = 0
and q.acceptedanswerid is null
and q.closeddate is null -- not closed
order by q.creationdate desc
```

Here is a screenshot of it in action:

[image: results of non answered questions]

As SEDE updated on a weekly basis the results might be a bit stale but you might tune that by selecting questions that were created longer ago as those are unlikely to be very volatile.

Keep in mind SEDE is updated once a week on Sunday.
Use the educational [SEDE Tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) written by the awesome [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162102/monica-cellio).
Say "Hi" in [SEDE chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).

Answer (score 1):

This will probably work with the Data Explorer (though it does not know your favourite tags; you have to supply those to the query). The results will be a bit stale (SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning).

But, there's a better option in the new [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/295232) feature, which is fortunately for you already available on Stack Overflow. I'm watching the [ios] tag on Stack Overflow; if I click the 'Unanswered questions' tab, and filter on 'My watched tags' and 'No answers', I get exactly what you want:

[image]

Comment: I have opt in for this feature, let's see when I get access to this feature.

Comment: The feature you shared will be very useful, still it will not fulfill my requirement, I want to list which I did not answer. So that I don't have to filter them out myself.