# How can someone review a late answer which was reviewed hours before?

Tags: support, review, late-answers

I am quite confused by [this sitution](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/1073532). At the time that I am writing, it states that:

- **Review completed 9 hours ago:**; two lines below, it says that a certain user “reviewed this 9 hours ago”.
- However, between those two lines, it says that that another user reviewed the answer a few minutes ago.

How can someone review a Late Answer hours after the review was completed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A situation like this could happen as follows:

- User A visits the Late Answers review queue and gets this item for reviewing.
- They do not review it yet, but leave the browser window open, and let the computer go to sleep.
- After 5 minutes, the item appears in the review queue again.
- This time, User B reviews the item.
- Several hours later, User A opens their computer again, and completes the review.
- Now you have two reviews on the same Late Answers review task.

Sometimes, the later review doesn't get registered; there might be some checks in place. But I've seen this happen more often.