# Is there an overview of questions for my subscribed sites with all my watched tags?

Tags: support, tags, subscription

Sometimes when looking to answer questions I want to be able to filter new questions by my set of watched tags. I can easily scroll through the list and watch for questions with yellow background. Is there a way to hide questions without watched tags?

When I'm active in multiple Stack Exchange sites I want this same feature, but not only showing questions for one community, but for all that I have an account for. Is there a way to display this information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to hide questions without watched tags?

Yes, this is one of the key features of the new [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/295232). You can [opt in](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/295232) to test it on Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange; other sites don't have this feature yet. On those sites, the only questions you can hide are those with tags you've ignored, but this leads to [a lot more pages you have to browse through](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNcgw.png)).

> When I'm active in multiple Stack Exchange sites I want this same feature, but not only showing questions for one community, but for all that I have an account for. Is there a way to display this information?

On stackexchange.com, there's a [Tag Filter](https://stackexchange.com/filters/); normally it lets you watch only a single tag over multiple sites, but there is a predefined filter for your favorited (watched) tags:

[image]