# Number of questions missing with Custom Question Lists

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, custom-question-lists

Without Custom Question Lists on the left, with Custom Question Lists on the right:

> [image]

The one with CQL is missing the part where it says "16,828,657 questions". I frequently use this number when I'm looking at smaller lists (e.g. questions with two specific tags) to see if it's practical to read all the questions or if I need to refine. I shouldn't have to scroll down to midway down the page (which is where the pagination controls are on narrower windows) and do math to get this number.

Comment: This has been mentioned and is actually [the top answer to the release post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313983/295232).

Comment: This issue [has been fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/313983/242059) as of May 6th 2019.

Answer (score 8):

As of the most recent update ([the "April" one that was actually posted in May](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327816/323179)), this has been fixed:

> [image]