# Why do I see tags that I don't want to watch?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-watching

Why do I sometimes see questions with tags that I don't watch on the home page?

I dislike it and I always have to add a new tag to my list of ignored tags.

Will there be an upgrade to this feature?

I ask this question because I see questions with tags that I don't have in my list of interesting tags.

Comment: They're being shown by default... If you don't want to see a tag, ignore it. Watching isn't "restrictive", it's to highlight and possibly email you about new ones

Comment: Are you asking if there is an option to only show posts which have tags on your watchlist? I don't think this setting exists, so you could always reword your question as a feature request - but have a read of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/feature-request/info) first.

Comment: Thanks for these many dislikes. Yes exactly Jake, I don't know how to see only tahs who are in watchlist.

Comment: @Fizik26 not dislikes, disagreements. There is a big difference.

Comment: OK I understand, thanks and sorry for my English :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tags watching only highlights questions; it does not block them. In the past I have seen people maintaining long lists of ignored tags (like you seem to be), but this isn't a good solution (as you've noted).

For Stack Overflow (and Meta Stack Overflow and here), you should use a custom view with Custom Question Lists:

> [image]

See [Custom question lists is available for testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/313940/323179) for more information.

---

Otherwise, you can just bookmark a search like [`[java] or [javascript] or [php]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+or+javascript+or+php).

Answer (score 14):

Tag watching is not a whitelist. Tags can be in 3 states: ignored, watched, and normal. Ignored means that such tags don't appear on your home page, ever, and any list of questions which include such tags will have that question grayed out. Watched tags means that the questions will appear highlighted on your home page (and on Stack Overflow, the filtering algorithm will filter out fewer questions with those tags). And normal is... normal.

The main thing that tag watching does is give you easy access to the tag itself. You see it on pages that list questions, so you can quickly select a tag and see the most recent questions on it.