# Why are Active and Votes two options in a dropdown on Stack Overflow while they are as two adjacent buttons on meta after doing a search?

Tags: discussion, search

Why are Active and Votes two options in a dropdown on Stack Overflow while they are as two adjacent buttons on meta after doing a search? When they are in a drop down, I have to make two mouse clicks instead of one. There's lots of white space to the left of that button strip. Two adjust buttons makes more sense.

Comment: Did you enable [custom question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179)?

Comment: I enabled it now and saw no difference. I still see a More dropdown. Maybe you can explain what change I should be expecting.