# Pagination links don't keep search terms on some sites with Custom Question Lists enabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, custom-question-lists

I noticed this on Stack Overflow, and it's happening here as well, but not on some other sites.

For example, go to

```
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion
```

Click on the link to page 2 or some other page, the `/tagged/discussion` is gone.

---

After opting out of custom question lists, it doesn't do this any more, so it seems to be related to that.

Comment: I wasn't able to recreate this, so I think the moderators wouldn't be able to recreate this bug too.

Comment: @Devealte oh, good to know. Maybe it's already fixed. I'll try it again. Or maybe just something about my system...

Comment: Also tried it on Stack Overflow, I still couldn't recreate this bug.
I'm also using Google Chrome, but I'm using a Windows 7 OS.

Comment: I don't think it's really related to that, to be honest, but I thought it couldn't hurt to add it just in case.

Comment: This looks like a [Custom Question lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179) bug, since I can repro it. @Devealte, I assume you're not opted in? And I assume Don't Panic is?

Comment: I think you should always add it, who knows, maybe Google Chrome is the issue.

Comment: @Laurel ohhh, I totally forgot about the custom question list thing. I bet you're right.

Comment: @Laurel Looks like you were right about that. It works properly after I opted out. Is this question in the right place, then? Sorry, I don't come around MSE much.

Comment: It's fine here. It would have also been fine on Meta Stack Overflow or even as an answer to the most recent announcement on MSE about Custom Question Lists (which specifically says you can post bugs as answers there).

Comment: @Laurel yeah, I actually just found that announcement after adding the tag for it. I probably would have posted it like that if I'd realized it was related to custom question lists initially.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This will be fixed in the next build.

This was the result of a logic bug.  The code that generates URLs can generate link relative to another list's link and looked like: `tagnames = relativeTo?.TagNames`.  Unfortunately, when `relativeTo` was null (because it was not passed in), `tagnames` was empty rather than the existing list's tags.  Now the code is `tagnames = relativeTo != null ? relativeTo.TagNames : TagNames`