# Why are On Hold Questions included in 'Active'

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, questions, on-hold

Lately there seems to have been a flood of poor relevance questions which are being put "On Hold" however these questions still show up in the Newest and Active lists - surely being "On Hold" they can/should not be classified as "Active"?

Can we please have a tab that gives us the questions that are eligible for answers.

Comment: Use search: https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bon-hold%5D+closed%3Ano+answers%3A0

Answer (score 9):

> Why are On Hold Questions included in 'Active'

Since they might have been edited, and the edit is so good that the question qualifies to be reopened. Yes, we have a review queue for that, but it's also good that the questions are visible in the regular Q&A pages. Also, if somebody vandalizes their post or edits in some offensive language, we *want* to be able to monitor that.

> Can we please have a tab that gives us the questions that are eligible for answers.

This is part of the aim of the new 'Custom Questions Lists' functionality. For more information about that, see [Custom question lists: finding questions you can answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/295232). If you don't want to use those, note that the default tab on the Questions page is 'Newest', not 'Active'. (Though the system remember your choice.) New questions can be on hold as well, but this won't happen that often as on the active tab. There's also a special Unanswered tab which might help you finding questions you can answer.

Comment: Couldn't they be hidden by default __until__ edited? Custom Questions List sound awesome for ___advanced___ users but finding questions that are not on hold seems like a fundamental to me.

Comment: People other than the question asker can edit them @Steve.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards True but what proportion of users actually do so? I suspect that it is a tiny fraction of 1%. The large number of `On Hold` questions just clutters the view for the remaining users.