# Watch combination tags?

Tags: support, tags, tag-watching

I am asking this on Meta, as I had previously read that the ability to monitor tags would affect Stack Exchange as a whole, despite my coming from Stack Overflow.

---

With several tags pending removal, and there not currently being a way to favorite combination tags, when/is this expected to be implemented?

Last I read the above was being looked at, but I haven't seen any posts indicating progression of that task.

---

E.g., [Excel-VBA] tag is pending removal, the desire to have a single click to monitor [Excel] [VBA], rather than click [VBA] and manually add in [Excel] as to avoid PPT, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will be implemented as phase II of the [Custom Question Lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/295232) project. You will be able to create a custom view with those tags

[image]

and access them from a dropdown in the tab and/or in the left navigation bar. Looks pretty, doesn't it?

[image]

Comment: There's something for everything on SE. :D