# Red icon in the custom questions list filter

Tags: support, custom-question-lists

Just before, I see a red icon in one of the saved filters of the side bar. When hovering on the icon it shows "New questions match this filter".

Is it part of the custom questions list new feature?

> [image: Filters]

**Update:** In the initial [custom question lists announcement - Phase III notifications](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312781/custom-question-lists-finding-questions-you-can-answer), I can see the information about the red icon indicators.

Is the feature released or due to code leakage I can see the red icon?

> [image: Red icon]

Comment: Not sure what you ask here? You mean to ask what's the red icon, why is it red, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

As you figured out, the red indicator light on MSE custom question lists is Custom Question Lists Phase 3.  I had turned it on for Meta because I wanted to test it prior to turning it on everywhere and writing an announcement meta post, but it isn't working 100% reliably so I decided to hold off on the full launch until we can track down the root cause. (The logic is working, but it appears to be ignoring/missing some updates.)

I decided to just leave the feature on unannounced so I could monitor it.

Comment: For testing in production you get an up vote ...

Comment: Is the test live again? I've seen it here on Meta SE and here is a SO screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0uit.png