# Add an advanced search option to custom filtering

Tags: feature-request, custom-filters

Currently the ability to [create custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions?edited=true) is limited by the options implemented as a separate user element (like radio button, check box or list of tags).

> [image: Edit custom filter]

I suggest adding an alternative ability for such functionality - add an edit box that will allow you to specify the raw search query (same as used in the top bar search box):

> [image: Top bar search]

For instance: [`[c++] score:2 created:2m hasaccepted:no duplicate:0`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D%20score%3A2%20created%3A2m%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20duplicate%3A0)
The key part here is the query result will be the posts with score at least 2 and created not later than 2 months ago.

I think that such feature will drastically increase the number of uses of custom filters. This will also let users to refuse the usage of browser specific bookmarks for the same purpose. Currently I'm using my web browser's bookmarks to make a custom search for posts that are interesting to me. These bookmarks are only usable for a specific SE site. So I think that the ability to store them linked with the SE profile is a good idea - you just need your SE account to get quick access to posts that interest you. You can use any browser on any device, not just one that allows bookmarks to sync across devices.

Comment: "add an edit box that will allow you to specify the raw search query". Early mock-ups had that. It never made it to the end user, even during testing.

Comment: @Laurel just curious where you got that information then?

Comment: When it was [first announced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312781/323179). Wow, it also put the lists in the left sidebar.

Comment: @Laurel well, question is why they ended up not adding it. Anyone ever mentioned it?

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars Probably because it was too complicated or expensive (computationally) to do. (Though there were also features like sorting by bounty size which were cut for no apparent reason.)

Comment: @Laurel actually it's not clear from announcement is there a search query like in the top bar or just a raw list of tags combined with logical operators.